# SP.ClientContext is appearing undefined

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I have below jquery code which in a sharepoint 2013 provider hosted app.

```
// variable used for cross site CSOM calls
var context;


//Wait for the page to load
$(document).ready(function () {

//Get the URI decoded SharePoint site url from the SPHostUrl parameter.
var spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
var appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
var spLanguage = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPLanguage'));

//Build absolute path to the layouts root with the spHostUrl
var layoutsRoot = spHostUrl + '/_layouts/15/';

//load all appropriate scripts for the page to function
$.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.Runtime.js',
    function () {
        $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.js',
            function () {
                //Load the SP.UI.Controls.js file to render the App Chrome
                $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.UI.Controls.js', renderSPChrome);

                //load scripts for cross site calls (needed to use the people picker control in an IFrame)
                $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', printAllListNamesFromHostWeb);

            });
    });
function printAllListNamesFromHostWeb() {
    var context;
    var factory;
    var appContextSite;
    var collList;
    context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, spHostUrl);
    this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
    collList = this.web.get_lists();
    context.load(collList);

}
});
```

This breaks at `context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);` and gives me below error:

> "0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this
>   action"

Please help me and let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to define variables globally. 
Try below code:

```
// variable used for cross site CSOM calls
var context,
    spHostUrl,
    appWebUrl,
    spLanguage,
    layoutsRoot,
    factory,
    appContextSite,
    collList;

//Wait for the page to load
$(document).ready(function () {

//Get the URI decoded SharePoint site url from the SPHostUrl parameter.
spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
spLanguage = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPLanguage'));

//Build absolute path to the layouts root with the spHostUrl
layoutsRoot = spHostUrl + '/_layouts/15/';

//load all appropriate scripts for the page to function
$.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.Runtime.js',
    function () {
        $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.js',
            function () {
                //Load the SP.UI.Controls.js file to render the App Chrome
                $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.UI.Controls.js', renderSPChrome);

                //load scripts for cross site calls (needed to use the people picker control in an IFrame)
                $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', printAllListNamesFromHostWeb);

            });
    });
function printAllListNamesFromHostWeb() {

    context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, spHostUrl);
    this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
    collList = this.web.get_lists();
    context.load(collList);

}
});
```

Hope this will help you!